# Как получить title страницы DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

Использую:

```
$this->doc = new DOMDocument;

        if($this->doc->loadHTMLFile($url)) {
           $metas = $this->doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        foreach ($metas as $meta) {
            if ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords') {
// Сюда заходит
                echo $meta->getAttribute('value'); // Всегда NULL
            }
        }
    }
```

Всегда, при получении значения найденного тега, выходит NULL

Comment: А в самом HTML-то всё правильно? Никаких проблем тут не вижу, всё находится, если `value` действительно есть.

Comment: На странице есть keywords, никаких ошибок так же не возникает

Comment: На строке:  
     if($this->doc->loadHTMLFile($url)) {}

Comment: url в студию который открываете

Comment: Например вот этот:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229658/getting-site-title-in-unknown-format-using-php-curl-and-dom-document

Comment: >Например

Например, в этом URL никаких мет с кейвордами не содержится. Так что не имейте наши мозги (это если вежливо)